# How to add Payment functionality in Shopping Cart

Tags: asp.net

I have got E commerce  web site in asp.net. I have added shopping cart using Datalist, shopping  cart functionality running fine now I want to add payment functionality.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific with your question: what payment processor, how far have you researched their API, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to integrate the PayPal checkout button with ASP.NET and get around the single form problem; it also shows how to grab the cart items data (caveat: own blog post):

[Integrate PayPal Checkout Button with ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/27/Integrate-PayPal-Checkout-Button-with-ASPNET-20.aspx)

This is also an expert reference showing how to construct the request to PayPal:

[PayPal Integration with ASP.NET article posted](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Sep/02/PayPal-Integration-with-ASPNET-article-posted)